# How do I detect a precise IE build from javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, user-agent

I have noticed that my app won't work in IE version 11.0.9600.18314. I see this number when I click "About Internet Explorer" button in the menu. Looks like I can't fix my error (it has something to do with WebGL), so at least I could warn users about it and ask them either to upgrade or to switch to another browser.

However when I look for this in `navigator.userAgent` - I don't those numbers after second dot. I can see only `"rv:11.0"` and that's it. No traces of "9600.18blablabla".

Can this info be found anywhere else perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: That is the wrong approach. Detect whether the browser supports WebGL and show the message if it does not. Also, [IE11 should support WebGL](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl).

Comment: @str, It's not that it does not support WebGL. It does support it, but displays stuff with bad glitches.

Comment: @Infer-on, no, there are no errors.

Comment: I am sorry, as you can read here http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Internet+Explorer you can't read the complete version number on IE in the user agent string

Comment: People who use IE are used to glitches anyway.